# Python ShopifyAPI get incoming inventory

Tags: python, python-3.x, shopify, shopify-api

My program currently reads inventory amounts from Shopify store via python ShopifyAPI but I'd like to also read the "incoming" inventory, is there a way to read it somehow?

[image]

Rough example of the current code structure:

```
class ApiSession:
    TOKEN = api_info.TOKEN
    SHOP_URL = api_info.SHOP_URL
    API_VERSION = api_info.API_VERSION

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = shopify.Session(self.SHOP_URL, self.API_VERSION, self.TOKEN)
        shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(self.session)
        self.shop = shopify.Shop.current()

    def get_all_products(self, limit=100):
        all_products = []
        get_next_page = True
        since_id = 0
        while get_next_page:
            products = shopify.Product.find(since_id=since_id, limit=limit)

            for product in products:
                all_products.append(product)
                since_id = product.id

            if len(products) < limit:
                get_next_page = False

        for i in all_products:
            print(i.variants[0].id, i.variants[0].inventory_quantity)
```

Tried everything by myself and read all around (including docs) for the answer without any luck.